# Resizing SVG circle on hover has overflow: hidden issue

Tags: css, svg

I have an SVG image that I want to resize on hover as in:

```
<svg>
                    <circle />
                    <path d="M20,31 C15.4189994,27.2225585 12.5023327,24.2225585 11.25,22 C10.2743515,20.6156479 10,19.6181623 10,18.1428571 C10,15.5113854 12.4883456,13 15,13 C17.3176009,13 18.9621484,13.8491346 20,15.5714286 C21.0382977,13.8491346 22.6828452,13 25,13 C27.5116544,13 30,15.5113854 30,18.1428571 C30,19.6181623 29.7256485,20.6156479 28.75,22 C27.497816,24.2225585 24.5811493,27.2225585 20,31 Z" />
                </svg>
```

CSS:

```
circle {
  fill: #EEE;
  cx: 20;
  cy: 20;
  r: 20;
}

path {
  fill: #CCC;
}

svg:hover circle {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  r: 22;
}
```

However, the circle gets cut-off on the sides when I hover because the SVG has an overflow hidden property. But I can't seem to override it. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Please see codepen:
https://codepen.io/aguerrero/pen/EeXJRx

Comment: circle elements don't have width and height properties.

Comment: Just add `svg{overflow:visible;}`. it should work. It works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking better at your code I see that it works in Chrome but can't work in other browsers.
I've made a few changes to your code:

1: I've added a viewBox to your svg, making it a little bigger than the icon, and I've centered it.

2. you can't modify presentational attributes like `cx` `cy` `r` in css. Presentational attributes belong to svg and can be modified in javascript

3.I've used javascript `mouseover / mouseout`events instead of css `hover`. If you don't want to use javascript you may try to use css scale for the circle.

```js
let circle= document.querySelector("circle")
circle.addEventListener("mouseover",()=>{
  circle.setAttributeNS(null,"r", 22)
})
circle.addEventListener("mouseout",()=>{
  circle.setAttributeNS(null,"r", 20)
})
```

```css
circle {fill: #EEE;}

path {fill: #CCC;}

svg{overflow:visible;
    border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-5 -5 50 50" width="44">
     <circle cx="20" cy="20" r=20 />
     <path id="test" 
                d="M20,31 
                   C15.4189994,27.2225585 12.5023327,24.2225585 11.25,22 
                   C10.2743515,20.6156479 10,19.6181623 10,18.1428571
                   C10,15.5113854 12.4883456,13 15,13 
                   C17.3176009,13 18.9621484,13.8491346 20,15.5714286
                   C21.0382977,13.8491346 22.6828452,13 25,13 
                   C27.5116544,13 30,15.5113854 30,18.1428571 
                   C30,19.6181623 29.7256485,20.6156479 28.75,22
                   C27.497816,24.2225585 24.5811493,27.2225585 20,31 Z" />
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to avoid the cut-off effect by adding `overflow: visible;` to the SVG element, [here's](https://jsfiddle.net/e2yLp4mv/) an example. Can't find [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/overflow#Browser_Compatibility) so I'm not sure if this is supported by all major browsers though.

Another way is probably to resize the svg viewBox using js or set a viewBox which contains the circle on hover, like this:

```css
circle { 
 fill: #EEE;
 cx: 20;
 cy: 20;
 r: 20;
}

path {
 fill: #CCC;
}

svg:hover circle {
 r: 22;
}
```

```html
<svg width="60" height="60" viewBox="-2 -2 60 60">
 <circle />
  <path d="M20,31 C15.4189994,27.2225585 12.5023327,24.2225585 11.25,22 C10.2743515,20.6156479 10,19.6181623 10,18.1428571 C10,15.5113854 12.4883456,13 15,13 C17.3176009,13 18.9621484,13.8491346 20,15.5714286 C21.0382977,13.8491346 22.6828452,13 25,13 C27.5116544,13 30,15.5113854 30,18.1428571 C30,19.6181623 29.7256485,20.6156479 28.75,22 C27.497816,24.2225585 24.5811493,27.2225585 20,31 Z" />
 </svg>
```